# making a custom method with an array print a value

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am trying to make this method print one of the four string messages contained within String[] strArr. I have tried doing this by calling the method in the main method, by typing many different forms of simpleArray(); and I have tried filling the parenthesis, writing it several different ways but nothing has worked. I have actually been working on it for days, and usually I give up and move on to a different part of the code.

Though it may seem impractical, I do need the method to be written similarly to the way it is because my project criteria states it must contain one argument and return void.

```
public static void simpleArray(String[] greetings) {

    String[] strArr = {"Welcome To CWU BANK!", "Thank you for using CWU ATM!", "Please insert DEBIT card", "We value your business!"};

        int i = (int)(Math.random() * strArr.length);
        System.out.println(strArr[i]);
    }
```

here is my main method, where I try to call the custom method in line 6.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException   {

    double amountToWithdrawl;
    double saveRandomBalance;
    double remainingBalance; 
    simpleArray();
    printStartupMessage();

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner keyboardDouble = new Scanner(System.in);

    saveRandomBalance = getRandomBalance();

    System.out.println("CHECKING BALANCE**** $" + saveRandomBalance);
              System.out.println("Would you like to withdrawl from CHECKING****? Y/N");
    String proceedWithWithdrawl = keyboard.nextLine();

    while (!proceedWithWithdrawl.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && !proceedWithWithdrawl.equalsIgnoreCase("n") 
                 && !proceedWithWithdrawl.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") && !proceedWithWithdrawl.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) 
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid response. Enter [Y] or [N].");
                 proceedWithWithdrawl = keyboard.next();
    } 

        switch(proceedWithWithdrawl)
        {
            case "N": 
            case "n":
            case "nO":   
            case "NO":
            case "No":
                System.out.println("Returning card... please wait...");
                System.out.println("Card returned. Thank you for using CWU Bank!");
                break;
            case "yeS":
            case "YEs":
            case "yEs":
            case "yES":   
            case "YeS":
            case "YES":
            case "Yes": 
            case "yes":
            case "y":
            case "Y":  
                System.out.println("Enter amount to withdrawl: ");
                amountToWithdrawl = keyboardDouble.nextDouble();
                remainingBalance = saveRandomBalance - amountToWithdrawl;
                remainingBalance = Math.round(remainingBalance * 100);
                remainingBalance = remainingBalance/100;

                if (amountToWithdrawl % 20 == 0 && amountToWithdrawl <= saveRandomBalance)
                {

                    System.out.println("Dispensing...");
                    System.out.println("ACCOUNT BALANCE: $" + remainingBalance);
                    System.out.println("$" + amountToWithdrawl + " has been withdrawn from CHECKING****");
                    System.out.println("Returning card... please wait...");
                    System.out.println("Card returned. Thank you for using CWU Bank!");
                    //CallDollarBill.dollarBill();
                }
                else if (amountToWithdrawl > saveRandomBalance)
                {
                    System.out.println("Insufficient Balance.");
                }
                else if (amountToWithdrawl % 20 != 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Please enter multiples of 20.");
                }
                //else
                //{
                //     System.out.println("invalid input");
                //}
        }
```

}

now, the error it provides is as follows.

firstDraftFinal.java:69: error: method simpleArray in class firstDraftFinal cannot be applied to given types;
                  simpleArray();
                  ^

required: String[]
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

1 error

I understand that part of the problem is probably int i (and strrArr) are integers, but I do not know what to do about this. I hired a tutor, but I ran out of time. I am also aware that the switch statement is not efficient, I will be changing that.
Thank you.

Comment: `simpleArray(new String[0]);`

Comment: Thank you so much Elliot! is there an easy way for me to write a range of 0-3 in place of zero since [i] doesn't work?

Comment: Why? You aren't using `greetings` in the method in any way. You can write whatever you like there, it isn't used.

Comment: I think I misspoke, what I meant to say is I am trying to enter something in place of zero that would cause it to print a single random piece of the array between 0-3 without removing the argument.

Comment: I spent 15 mins and I still didn't understand this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code specifies a parameter that is not used; while it's unclear why you would want to do this, you can simply pass null.  However, maybe what you intended was to pass the list of greetings; i.e. see second version below.

```
    class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Per your current code.
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) simpleArray(null);
            System.out.println("");

            // What you may be looking for.
            String[] strArr = { "Welcome To CWU BANK!", "Thank you for using CWU ATM!", "Please insert DEBIT card",
            "We value your business!" };
            for (int i=0; i<10; i++) simpleArray2(strArr);
        }

        public static void simpleArray(String[] greetings) {
            String[] strArr = { "Welcome To CWU BANK!", "Thank you for using CWU ATM!", "Please insert DEBIT card",
                    "We value your business!" };

            int i = (int) (Math.random() * strArr.length);
            System.out.println(strArr[i]);
        }

        public static void simpleArray2(String[] greetings) {
            int i = (int) (Math.random() * greetings.length);
            System.out.println(greetings[i]);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed response. I did try both ways and they pass the full list though, what I was trying to do is just pass one of the four messages once, randomly. I cant figure out how to make it choose one of the four, and then print that from the main method.

Comment: Typically, simpleArray2 would simply return the String (instead of void). But assuming you want simpleArray2 to choose and main to print, you could alter the greetings array so that index zero is the random selection.  For example, String tmp=greetings[0]; greetings[0]=greetings[i]; greetings[i]=tmp;  Then in the main method you would print strArr[0]. *Sorry for this delayed response; just got back from a trip.*

Answer (score 0):

You have compile error because you didn't pass any arguments to method that require them, just pass to your method any string array, because you don't use passed argument in this method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException   {

    double amountToWithdrawl;
    double saveRandomBalance;
    double remainingBalance; 
    simpleArray(new String[0]);
    printStartupMessage();
```

To continue refactor your code you may want to get rid of this argument (pay attention if other parts of code may use it) and rewrite it like this:

```
public static void printGreetings() {
     String[] greetings = {"Welcome To CWU BANK!",
                             "Thank you for using CWU ATM!",
                             "Please insert DEBIT card",
                             "We value your business!"
     };
     int random = new Random().nextInt(greetings.length);
     System.out.println(greetings[random]);
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, this definitely works more cleanly than what ive had and I appreciate it. I just have an inconvenient part of my project rubric that requires me to keep an argument in the method.